# cómo mostrar un dato obtenido de la api alphavantage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

hola quiero mostrar en un span algunos datos de esa api pero no se por que en mi codigo obtengo un "undefined" ya he buscado pero no encuentro algo que me resuelva la situación pido de su ayuda

esta es la salida de la petición

```
{
    "Realtime Currency Exchange Rate": {
        "1. From_Currency Code": "BTC",
        "2. From_Currency Name": "Bitcoin",
        "3. To_Currency Code": "USD",
        "4. To_Currency Name": "Dolar america",
        "5. Exchange Rate": "11942249.99040000",
        "6. Last Refreshed": "2019-03-06 02:26:57",
        "7. Time Zone": "UTC"
    }
}
```

y este es el codigo que tengo hasta ahora

```
$.ajax({
                url:url,
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data){
                    for(let i in data) {
       console.log(data[i])
     }
                    console.log(data);
                    console.log(data[0]);
                },
                error:function(){console.log("error fatal");}
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

al hacer una consulta ajax, debes definir de que tipo de petición se trata,GET o POST,y por los que me he podido fijar en la API, las consultas se hacen a través de la url por lo que la petición sería GET.Después, defino de que tipo de datos  se va a recibir,en este caso es de tipo json la respuesta.Por último, recorro los datos recogidos por el servidor pero el índice lo marco por el nombre y al recorrerlo empiezo por el indice Realtime Currency Exchange Rate y recorro lo que hay dentro de ese elemento.

a ver si con esto te puedes apañar:

```
  $.ajax({
url:"https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=CURRENCY_EXCHANGE_RATE&from_currency=BTC&to_currency=CNY&apikey=demo",
method:"GET",
dataType:"json",
success:function(data){
  console.log(data);
     $.each(data["Realtime Currency Exchange Rate"],function(index,value){
    console.log(value);

  });

},
error:function(data){

}});
```

Comment: lo tienes editado @alfap